# Text-wrapping and text-backgroud-color in Piston-2DGraphics (Rust)?

Tags: rust, game-engine, game-development, text-rendering, rust-piston

1 - How to wrap text to the next line, once it's out of the window.
2 - How do we handle the background-color of a text field.

I'm very new to game dev, so this might be a naive question to ask.

Comment: try `textwrap` cargo. divide your window width by font size(approx) to get count of symbols max per line. if need other more complex, checkout each symbols size via Unicode width package.